# Module not found: Can't resolve '@swc/helpers/src/_class_private_field_init.mjs' using NextUI with Next.js 13

Tags: node-modules, next.js13, nextui

I´m trying to use NextUI with the latest version of Next.js 13. Following the official documentation of NextUI I have followed these steps:

1. Install NextUI for Next.js

`npm i @nextui-org/react`

2.Go to pages/_app.js and add this:

```
// 1. import `NextUIProvider` component
import { NextUIProvider } from '@nextui-org/react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    // 2. Use at the root of your app
    <NextUIProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </NextUIProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

3.Go to pages/_document.js and add this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { CssBaseline } from '@nextui-org/react';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return {
      ...initialProps,
      styles: React.Children.toArray([initialProps.styles])
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>{CssBaseline.flush()}</Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

After that i run `npm run dev` command and the console show the following error:

```
error - ./node_modules/@internationalized/date/dist/import.mjs:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '@swc/helpers/src/_class_private_field_init.mjs'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@react-aria/i18n/dist/real-module.js
./node_modules/@react-aria/i18n/dist/module.js
./node_modules/@nextui-org/react/esm/index.js
./pages/_app.js
```

Does anyone know what might be happening?

I´ve checked and "_class_private_field_init.mjs" is in the right path. And I have also tried reinstalling the node_modules

Answer (score 6):

Upgrading to 13.4.7 worked for me

Comment: This works for my project. Thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

In your terminal copy and paste

```
npm install @swc/helpers
```

The issue should be solved.

Comment: that doest help

Answer (score 3):

If you will use nextjs version "13.3.0" the issue should be resolved. Important note is that you should use exact version. More info in this comment https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48593#issuecomment-1519914997

Answer (score 1):

it working well with `"next": "13.3.0"` version. Try to downgrade the next version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the lower version while the bug is being fixed in future releases.

`package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
        "next": "13.2.4",
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case this solution did not work, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the lower version while the bug is being fixed in future releases.

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
        "next": "13.2.4",
    }
}
```

then run npm install.

---

It works in my case.

Comment: This has worked for me as well in an NX project.